# azure pricing for api management and table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-api-management

I have built API gateway (azure api management)

and its getting requests from Zone2 out of azure cloud,

as soon as i get reuqests, this API gateway does request to Azure Storage API,

and get responses, send responses to client.

its like this,

Client <---> Azure API Management <---> Azure Storage API <---> Table Storage
        (1)                        (2)                      (3)

Azure is pricing both number of requests and outbound data transfer right?

then pricing for all (1),(2),(3)??

Comment: Is your API and storage account in the same region?

Comment: yes only client is out of Cloud and different zone

Comment: and actually (1),(2),(3) is meaning each of single <--->

Comment: I see. Then the answer is yes. You will pay for (1), (2), and (3). Apart from number of requests and outbound data transfer, you will also pay for the data stored in table storage.

Comment: oh ... really? ... well OK thanx alot! yes of course.! actually one more question , do you know how to find out the current capacity of Table storage? seems like Azure  support that for only Blob...

Comment: Please see my answer here for table storage size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481445/azure-table-storage-how-much-data-am-i-using. HTH.

Comment: and actually i saw this "Is data transfer between Azure services located within the same region charged?"
No. For example, an Azure SQL database in the same region will not have any additional data transfer costs. which meaning i dont need to pay for (3)....? isnt it?

Comment: That's what I asked you first :). You're correct. You only pay for outbound data transfer if the data goes out of the region. So if your API and Storage account are in the same region, any data sent to API by Storage will not be chargeable.

Comment: ok clear! thanx alot !!!